# trying to get an integer variable out from an array list

Tags: java, arraylist, integer

I have a string Array List called casesArrayList. I have a few words and some numbers in the Array List ... I am trying to get the numbers out of the array List and make the integers so I could make some calculations with these numbers. Here is my code that does not work :

My array list looks like this : **Opened Opened Opened Opened Opened Opened My Case 300000 100 25000 0 500 400000 100000 75000 1 5 500000 75 25 750000 1000 10 200000 400 750** , if I use `System.out.print(casesArrayList.get(j) + " ")` in a for loop.

```
    for (int j = 0; j < casesArrayList.size(); j++)
       {
        if (!casesArrayList.get(j).equals("My Case") &&  !casesArrayList.get(j).equals("Opened")) {
          System.out.print(casesArrayList.get(j) + " ");
       }
```

// at this point the output is : **300000 100 25000 0 500 400000 100000 75000 1 5 500000 75 25 750000 1000 10 200000 400 750**

// the error is in the next line :

```
       int c = (int) casesArrayList.get(j);
       System.out.print(c + " ");
    }
```

How could I get the numbers out of the array list and make the variables, because parseInt, valueOf or (int) does not work .

I edited the code :

```
for ( int j = 0; j < casesArrayList.size(); j++) {
        if (!casesArrayList.get(j).equals("My Case") &&  !casesArrayList.get(j).equals("Opened")) {
          System.out.print(casesArrayList.get(j) + " ");
       }

        try {
            int c = Integer.parseInt(casesArrayList.get(j));
            System.out.print(casesArrayList.get(j) + " ");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
       }
          System.out.print(c + " ");
    }
```

The error message still :
no suitable method found for parseInt(java.lang.Object)

method java.lang.Integer.parseInt(java.lang.String) is no applicable ;

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxl0o.png

Thank you guys so much, I am not a Java expert, I made some pretty obvious mistakes, but I finally made it work ... @ Suresh was right, the perfectly working code is :

```
 for (int j = 0; j < casesArrayList.size(); j++) {

         if (!casesArrayList.get(j).equals("My Case") &&  !casesArrayList.get(j).equals("Opened")) {
             total = total + (Integer.parseInt((String)casesArrayList.get(j)));
             n = n + 1;
         }
         average = total / n;
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("The total is "+ total);
    System.out.println("The average is "+ average);
```

Comment: So it's not an ArrayList<String>, but a raw ArrayList. Don't use raw types. Your variable type should be ArrayList<String>. Otherwise, you can't know anything about the types of the objects in the list, and need to cast them first: `String s = (String) casesArrayList.get(j)`. Where did you learn Java? It seems like your teacher or tutorial or book still teached Java like it was many years ago.

Comment: @JB I just saw your comment, you are right... I will edit my code, now is raw type /... I thought is String Array List because of this : for ( int i = 0; i < casesArray.length ; i++) {
            casesArrayList.add(new String (Integer.toString(casesArray[i])));
        } ...  I am in high school, I learn computer programming at a lower level, I do not know every part of Java correctly, so if you have time, fell free to correct my code, I will send the whole project to you , if I can ... I will be right back in 1.5 hours

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `casesArrayList` is a String `ArrayList` each value of it is a `String`, you need to parse that string. Not a direct cast

```
try {
     System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(casesArrayList.get(j)));
} catch(NumberFormatException ex){
   // do something here if it is not a number     
}
```

see [Integer.parseInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29)

As I see the screenshot you mentioned, It's not a String ArrayList and you are getting a type as Object (*not sure*). Try to cast it to String and then try.

```
  System.out.println(Integer.parseInt((String)casesArrayList.get(j)));
```

Comment: Don't forget to parse your Strings within a try/catch block! You'll need to catch NumberFormatExceptions & deal with the items in the list that aren't actually numerical values.

Comment: @MichaelHillman If the list is supposed to contain values that represent integers, it's better to let the exception bubble rather than catch it.

Comment: Really good idea, but it gives me the error message : no suitable method found for parseInt(java.lang.Object) ...method java.lang.parseInt(java.lang.String) is not applicable ;

Comment: @JBNizet OP states that the list intentionally contains both words & numbers :)

Comment: @MichaelHillman: but he also checks that the value is not any of the expected words before parsing. And the most effective way to handle the exception is to throw another one, so why catch the exception in the first place?

Comment: @UtherPendragon Can you please let us know the error message ?

Comment: @Suresh edited to catch a more specific exception and add a link to the javadoc of `parseInt`

Comment: @RC. That's a valuable Edit. Thank you.

Comment: @Suresh the error is : no suitable method found for parseInt(java.lang.Object) ...method java.lang.parseInt(java.lang.String) is not applicable

Comment: @UtherPendragon Have you imported `java.lang.Integer`  ?

Comment: @UtherPendragon: that doesn't look like an exact and complete error message. Post the exact and complete error message. And post the actual code you tried (by editing your question).

Comment: It doesn't mean that each element is a String (see generics type erasure). List can contain items of reference type. It'd be nice if this precondition was given by the topic starter.

Comment: @ahanin Yes, OP started with that line in his question .`I have a string Array List called casesArrayList.`

Comment: @Suresh Yes, I imported it, same error ...I edited the code to the Try-Catch block. but still does not accept the parseInt

Comment: Can you please edit your post with new code and line number with complete error message ?? as JB said.

Comment: @Suresh I put up a link with a picture, it is a screenshot with my error, I use BlueJ, so the errors are described like that ... still does not want to accept parseInt ...my import is import java.lang.Integer.*;

Comment: @ Suresh thanks for the help, your last suggestion worked, check out the end of the question ,I edited it, I have posted the working codes

Comment: It would be very helpful If you say that the ArrayList is declared with a raw type and not with String. Obviously that took the time to resolve the issue. Anyways glad to help you out. Good luck with the project.

Comment: Hi @SURESH ATTA . You helped me before, could you help me again, I have a different kind of issue this time. Could you take a look at stackoverflow.com/questions/23233993/… or stackoverflow.com/questions/23189706/… please, and could you tell me how to do it properly ?

Answer (score 0):

Try looping through your list and doing this.

```
boolean isNum = false;
try {
   Integer.parseInt(str);
   isNum = true;
}catch(Exception ex){
   isNum = false;     
}
```

This will tell you which elements are ints and which are not.
Then take just those which are ints and process them as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Let's `casesArrayList` be defined like:

```
List<String> casesArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
casesArrayList.add("Opened");
casesArrayList.add("Opened");
casesArrayList.add("My Case");
casesArrayList.add("200s0");
casesArrayList.add("1000");
```

your code should look like:

```
for (int j = 0; j < casesArrayList.size(); j++) {
    if (!casesArrayList.get(j).equals("My Case") && !casesArrayList.get(j).equals("Opened")) {
        try {
            int c = Integer.parseInt(casesArrayList.get(j));
            System.out.print(casesArrayList.get(j) + " ");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not very elegant to parse the String to Integer, plus, it potentially throws exceptions.

You can use regular expression matching instead:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("Word", "12321");
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
for (String e : list) {
    if (!e.matches("\\s*-?\\d+\\s*")) {
        strings.add(e);
    }
}
```